# Как выполнить обработку нажатия только один раз?

Tags: c#

```
  private void Form1_Mouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Don't use \"p\"! ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        }
```

Метод срабатывает при каждом нажатии, а мне нужно только один раз.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отпишитесь от события после первого срабатывания:

```
private void Form1_Mouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Don't use \"p\"! ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
    MouseDown -= Form1_Mouse;
}
```

Comment: Наверное лучше сначала отписаться, а потом уже что то делать

Comment: @tym32167, gui работает в одном потоке, поэтому разницы, наверное, быть не должно

Comment: ну я вообще говорил про общий случай, но и в вашем случае `MessageBox.Show` вероятно создает новый фрейм (моё предположение), и если бы он не блочил начальное окно, по окну можно было бы накликать ещё, пока первый messageBox не закрыт

Answer (score 2):

```
        bool res = false;
        private void Form1_Mouse(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

            if (!res)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Don't use \"p\"! ", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                res = true;
            }

        }
```